# GIMP: do not move layer to top when transforming

Tags: gimp, layers, transform

Using GIMP 2.99, I'm trying to fit photographs into a photo frame with cutouts. I created the cutouts in a top layer, and am trying to visually scale the photos on the below layers so I can make a (part of a) photograph fit into the frame in an aesthetically pleasing way. This means it is important the frame remains visible.

However, GIMP always brings my entire photo layer to the top while transforming (scaling) it, hiding the layer with the cutouts below. Is there a away to alter this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an Image Opacity slider in all of the Transform Tool Options in GIMP.  Set it to something like 50% or approximately half-way.

Then you will be able to see through the image while you transform.

For example, here I set the image opacity slider in the Tool Options before using the Unified Transform tool in GIMP 2.10.

[image]

Comment: not exactly what I was hoping for from GIMP, but it'll do. Thanks for the GIF demo too :D

Answer (score 0):

Scale the frame. I bet you more likely let the frame get the unavoidable quality loss that scaling causes.

Answer (score -1):

Uncheck the 'show a preview of the transform_grided image' box, maybe that helps

Comment: thanks! where is this option?